# Glycon joints not supported in Blender--I'm trying to fix it.

Tags: motion-capture

The FBX file my mocap system generates is not compatible with Blender, and I'm trying to figure out why. Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

This is what it looks like in Blender, which is wrong:
[image: This is what it looks like in Blender (wrong)]

And this is what it looks like in LightWave, which is correct:
[image: This is what it looks like in LightWave (correct)]

The files themselves, and a description of the problem can be found here:
http://chiltonwebb.com/GlyconBlender.zip

I really want to make sure Glycon supports Blender without a bunch of hoops to jump through, but I can't wrap my head around what's going wrong. So any help or suggestions here would be greatly appreciated!!

More on Glycon:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgoc-0e-PCg

Thank you,
-Chilton Webb

Comment: can it export bvh files? blender imports them well enough.

Comment: It can. But I figured it out. Blender works perfectly now. The problem (if anyone else searches for this) is that blender doesn't like finding the transform distances in the FBX files except for the root node. Subsequent transform distances, even if they're minuscule, result in giant control UI widgets. By removing the transform distances entirely, everything looks perfect.